# Why is reading stdin from cat pipe faster than directly reading the file?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, file-io

I've noticed that this:

```
cat 1GB.txt | ./program_that_reads_stdin
```

Is faster than this:

```
./program_that_reads_file_directly
```

Note: I always flush the page cache before timing these programs:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

**UPDATE**: I tried Jerry's single-threaded read-from-file implementation, it is slower than both the `cat` version as well as my multithreaded implementation:

```
cat | ./read from stdin: 0.57s to 0.61s
./read_from_file_multithreaded: 0.60s to 0.64s
./read_from_file_singlethreaded (Jerry's answer): 0.64s to 0.71s
```

Changing the buffer size did not make the single-threaded read-from-file implementation run faster.

In fact I had tried several single-threaded read-from-file implementations previously, and they were all slower than my multithreaded implementation - hence why I decided to try to speed up my multithreaded implementation instead of sticking to single-thread read-from-file.

The `program_that_reads_stdin` is the `example` program referred to below, while the `program_that_reads_file_directly` is the `b3sum` program referred to below.

The `b3sum` program directly opens the file `1GB.txt` and reads and processes it using a producer-consumer pattern using two threads, while the `example` binary is a single-thread program that simply calls `read` on `stdin` repeatedly.

Here is the source code for the `b3sum` program (this is the one that I wrote):

```cpp
#include "blake3.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

static constexpr std::size_t MAXFILESIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
static constexpr std::size_t BUFSIZE = 65536; // 128 * 1024 * 1024;
static constexpr std::size_t NUMBUFS = MAXFILESIZE / BUFSIZE + 1;


// globals
std::mutex mut;
unsigned char* buffers[NUMBUFS];
std::queue<char*> available_bufs; // queue of buffers which are available for consumers to consume
int bytes_read[NUMBUFS] = {0};
std::condition_variable cv;
// write_head is the shared variable associated with cv
int write_head = 0; // index of buffer currently being written to - hasn't been fully written yet.

void producer_thread()
{
    int fd;
    int i, n=0;
    const char* fname = "1GB.txt";

    if ((fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        printf("%s: cannot open %s\n", fname);
        exit(2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBUFS; ++i){
        unsigned char* buf = buffers[i];
        int n = read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE);
        bytes_read[i] = n;
        // signal to consumer thread
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            write_head = i + 1;
            //std::cout << "new write_head:" << write_head << std::endl;
        }
        cv.notify_all();

        if ( n == 0 ){ // if we have reached end of file
            std::cout << "Read to end of file" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Buffers used: " << i;
            return;
        }
    }
}


void consumer_thread(int thread_id){
  // Initialize the hasher.
  blake3_hasher hasher;
  blake3_hasher_init(&hasher);

    // read write_head
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBUFS; ++i){
        // wait for buffer to become available for reading]
        //puts("waiting...");
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return i < write_head; });
        }
        //puts("finished waiting");
        int n = bytes_read[i];
        //std::cout << "bytes read: " << n << std::endl;
        if ( n == 0 ) {
            // print output
            // Finalize the hash. BLAKE3_OUT_LEN is the default output length, 32 bytes.
            uint8_t output[BLAKE3_OUT_LEN];
            blake3_hasher_finalize(&hasher, output, BLAKE3_OUT_LEN);

            // Print the hash as hexadecimal.
            printf("blake3 hash: ");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < BLAKE3_OUT_LEN; i++) {
                printf("%02x", output[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            return ;
        }
        // now process the data
        unsigned char* buf = buffers[i];
        blake3_hasher_update(&hasher, buf, n);
    }

}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    // create shared buffers
    puts("Allocating buffers");
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int alignment = 4096;
    
    // allocate the buffers and put them into the global buffers array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBUFS; ++i){
        unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*) memalign(alignment, BUFSIZE);
        buffers[i] = buf;
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    /* Getting number of milliseconds as a double. */
    duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = end - start;
    std::cout << "time taken" << ms_double.count() << "ms\n";
    puts("finished allocating buffers");

    // start producer and consumer threads
    std::thread t1(producer_thread), t2(consumer_thread, 1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it like this (you need to first build libblake.a from the BLAKE3 C sources which you can find [here](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/tree/master/c)):

```
g++ -c b3sum.cc -O3; g++ b3sum.o -o b3sum libblake3.a
```

Now if you run this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time ./b3sum
```

With the BUFSIZE set to `65536`, it takes on average 0.85s to run on my machine.

But if I set the BUFSIZE to `128 * 1024 * 1024`, then it only takes on average 0.63s to run on my machine. I can't think of a reason why increasing the BUFSIZE would make it so much faster, other than it reduces the number of syscalls - but I believe this is not the reason, see below.

Now, the example program is directly from the blake3 repo here: https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/blob/master/c/example.c It is very simple, I'll include the source code here:

```cpp
#include "blake3.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  // Initialize the hasher.
  blake3_hasher hasher;
  blake3_hasher_init(&hasher);

  // Read input bytes from stdin.
  unsigned char buf[65536];
  while (1) {
    ssize_t n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (n > 0) {
      blake3_hasher_update(&hasher, buf, n);
    } else if (n == 0) {
      break; // end of file
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  // Finalize the hash. BLAKE3_OUT_LEN is the default output length, 32 bytes.
  uint8_t output[BLAKE3_OUT_LEN];
  blake3_hasher_finalize(&hasher, output, BLAKE3_OUT_LEN);

  // Print the hash as hexadecimal.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < BLAKE3_OUT_LEN; i++) {
    printf("%02x", output[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, all it does is just read 64KB from stdin at a time, and then process it.

Running this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time cat 1GB.txt | ./example
```

The result is around 0.59s. There is significant variance but the running time of the `cat 1GB.txt | ./example` quite often (maybe 50% of the time) drops below 0.6s - I've seen 0.57s, whereas the running time of the `./b3sum` NEVER dips below 0.6s. So the `cat` version is I would estimate around 0.3s faster than the non-cat version.

I do not understand how this is possible.

On the Raspberry Pi, using `cat` consistently made things slower. For example, on my Raspberry Pi `cat file | openssl sha1` was **consistently** slower than `sha1sum file` - `cat file | openssl sha1` took around 14.5s whereas `sha1sum file` took around 12.7s. However, on my current machine, `cat file | openssl sha1` is consistently faster than `sha1sum file`: `sha1sum file` takes around 1.2s on average while `cat file | openssl sha1` takes around 0.9s on average.

In the above case I am assuming the reason the `cat` version is faster on my current machine is because `openssl sha1` is using a faster implementation of `sha1` than `sha1sum`.

However, in my case I am using the same code for computing the BLAKE3 hash so there should be no reason why the `cat` version is faster than my producer-consumer implementation.

Since reducing the BUFSIZE made my implementation faster, I tried other values for the BUFSIZE but they did not reduce the running time significantly (it looked like there was some kind of U-curve, and 128mb is near the sweet spot).

My hypothesis was that it's the number of syscalls that was making my program slow, since increasing the BUFSIZE from 64KB to 128MB would have reduced the number of syscalls.

However, I looked at strace output and it looks like the `cat` version was actually making way more syscalls (excerpt):

```
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
```

And likewise for the example program that was reading from stdin.

So I'm sure it's not the number of syscalls that's making my program slower. What else could it be?

Comment: Each syscall is, comparatively, expensive. The larger the buffer, the fewer calls to read() are needed to read all input, the less time it takes. Change the size of the buffer to just 1 byte and see how long it takes now... That's precisely why std::streambuf exists. I expect this to be explained in every textbook on OS design and implementation, at least it was back when I was studying it.

Comment: Using two threads may well slow things down here.  Try with just one.

Comment: Because using two threads to read one file is literally a waste of time.

Comment: All of the single-threaded read-from-file implementations that I've tried have been slower than my multithreaded version, including the one in Jerry's answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The `cat` version issues way more syscalls (since the `cat` program reads and then writes 128KB at a time, and the `example` program reads `64KB` at a time) but is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming two algorithm implementations are equal, why one runs faster than another one.

`cat 1GB.txt | ./program_that_reads_stdin` are two processes that run on different CPU cores. The processes are synchronized with blocking IO operations and the OS task scheduler prioritizes processes that wait for IO completions.

`./program_that_reads_file_directly` is a single process with two threads that are synchronized with a condition variable and a mutex. The OS task scheduler does not prioritize such threads.

If you make `program_that_reads_file_directly` a single thread application, it may make it to run faster, but slower when one with a pipe, because two processes win a single process.

Comment: "The OS task scheduler does not prioritize such threads" any more information on this?

Comment: It's a big topic. In short, IO operations are slow by their nature. If an app waits for IO completion,  the OS scheduler moves such processes on the top of a task priority queue when data is avaialble. It makes apps more  responsive. Processes that wait for mutexes and conditional variables will run in a regular priority queue order, they even may be moved to down if other processes wait for IO.

Comment: Hi, I ran Jerry's single-threaded read-from-file implementation, it is consistently slower than both the `cat` version and my multithreaded version. In fact I had tried several single-threaded read-from-file implementations previously, and they are all slower than my multithreaded implementation.

Comment: @273K I ran my process with the highest priority using `time ionice -c 1 -n 0 nice -n -20 ./b3sum` and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I should add that I don't have anything else running on that system that could be stealing CPU or IO. `atop` says CPU and disk is 0% busy.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to me that this is mostly about your use of multithreading. I'd compare by using code that's otherwise essentially identical, but one reading from standard input and the other reading directly from the file.

To do that, let's modify their code ever so slightly to allow it to open and read from a specified file if so desired.

```cpp
#include "blake3.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Initialize the hasher.
  blake3_hasher hasher;
  blake3_hasher_init(&hasher);

  // if they specify a file, use it; otherwise stdin:
  int infile = argc < 2 ? STDIN_FILENO : open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

  // Read input bytes from stdin.
  unsigned char buf[65536];
  while (1) {
    ssize_t n = read(infile, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (n > 0) {
      blake3_hasher_update(&hasher, buf, n);
    } else if (n == 0) {
      break; // end of file
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  // Finalize the hash. BLAKE3_OUT_LEN is the default output length, 32 bytes.
  uint8_t output[BLAKE3_OUT_LEN];
  blake3_hasher_finalize(&hasher, output, BLAKE3_OUT_LEN);

  // Print the hash as hexadecimal.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < BLAKE3_OUT_LEN; i++) {
    printf("%02x", output[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Doing a quick comparison, I get results like this:

```
$ time cat /tmp/bigfile | ./example
55c6dac98fbc9a388f619f5f4ffc4c9fdd3eb37eab48afd68b65da90ef3070b1

real    0m0.512s
user    0m0.370s
sys 0m0.528s

$ time ./example /tmp/bigfile
55c6dac98fbc9a388f619f5f4ffc4c9fdd3eb37eab48afd68b65da90ef3070b1

real    0m0.441s
user    0m0.329s
sys 0m0.113s
```

There's also a third option: redirect the program's standard input to the file:

```
$ time ./example < /tmp/bigfile
55c6dac98fbc9a388f619f5f4ffc4c9fdd3eb37eab48afd68b65da90ef3070b1

real    0m0.442s
user    0m0.321s
sys 0m0.121s
```

I ran it several times to be sure, and although the difference is small (only about 50 ms), it does seem reliable that using `cat` is slower. I don't see any reliable difference between opening and reading the file, and redirecting its standard input to the file (this particular run is 1 ms faster opening the file, but they both vary much more than that from one run to the next, so that's probably meaningless).

Comment: Hi, did you flush the page cache before running these programs? `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` When I ran your program, it took 0.64 to 0.71 seconds, compared to the `cat` version which takes around 0.57 to 0.61 seconds.

Comment: I've tried it both with and without flushing the cache. While they (of course) run slower after flushing the cache, using `cat` is consistently slower than just reading the file.

Comment: I tried the `time ./example < /tmp/bigfile` method too and it is also consistently slower than the `cat` version: it takes around 0.63 to 0.77 seconds compared to the `cat` which takes 0.55 to 0.64s.

Comment: @1f604: I tend to find that somewhat suspect, but I guess if it makes you happy to believe it, I'm not going to argue it.